# Manjaro Update Error

Tags: networking, upgrade, manjaro, hostname

I'm on Manjaro since 1 year now and since two months I'm in China, without stable network to do any update. Yesterday, I ran "pacman -Syu" the update face fine, no errors. But when I reboot, I noticed a few changes:

- My laptop host name was changed from "n214-mac" to "Manjaro"
- I cannot connect to my wifi, and I ran "ip addr" and ifconfig but I could not find my wifi interface....
- The terminal is buggy, i cannot delete some characters sometimes and icons are not properly displayed.

I don't know what to do since, there is no error message when I boot. Checked "journalctl".
Can someone help me to troubleshoot? Thanks in advance

Comment: Without providing actual answers to your questions, if you know you're gonna find yourself without an Internet connection for longer periods of time , perhaps Arch is not the distro for you, as it changes often, being a rolling release distribution. Perhaps something more stable like Debian Stable (duh!) or CentOS would suit you better.

Comment: Not a specifically safe procedure, but you could roll back to a specific date. [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Linux_Archive#How_to_restore_all_packages_to_a_specific_date) - needs internet connection!

Comment: @schaiba Thanks, should have anticipated that !

Comment: @Fiximan Better than nothing, I will try this. I still have internet connection when I plug my phone on usb tethering mode. But even if it works, how should I update after that?